# Powermail use marker/variable as link in RTE Submit Page

Tags: typo3, powermail

I want to use a Powermail marker as a href in the RTE at the submit Page.

```
I.e. <a href="{myMarker}">myText</a>
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You must enable HTML within RTE.
See option misc.htmlForHtmlFields at [docs](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/powermail/stable/ForAdministrators/BestPractice/MainTypoScript/Index.html?highlight=settings%20html).
After that it should be possible to use your code or [fluid link viewhelper](https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/master/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Link/Typolink.html) e.g.

```
 <f:link.typolink parameter="{themarker}">the Text</f:link.typolink>
```